# How can I use the value of a checkbox to hide the div with the corresponding ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, input

I'm using a set of checkboxes with each corresponding to a div containing content. I'm trying to only use a single function for all the checkboxes.

I've created a function which looks for any checkbox being clicked, identifies if the checkbox is checked and then attempts to show the corresponding content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                $($(this).value).show();
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                $($(#this).value).hide();               
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="dieConstant" value="'#dc'"> Show Dielectric Constant<br>


<div id="#dc" style="display:none">
    content
</div>
```

When the checkbox is ticked, the content in the "dc" div should appear, but it does not. Note that replacing " $(this).show(); " with " $(#dc).show(); " gives the intended result and that is what I need, but it needs to work will all checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose it is better to use `data-attribute`. I named it `data-id`. The `value` attribute is then still available to hold real values.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $($(this).data('id')).show();
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $($(this).data('id')).hide();

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="dieConstant" value="" data-id="#dc"> Show Dielectric Constant (dc)<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="dieConstant" value="" data-id="#dc2"> Show Dielectric Constant (dc2)<br>

<div id="dc" style="display:none">
    content dc
</div>

<div id="dc2" style="display:none">
    content dc2
</div>
```

A good suggestion from @Rory McCrossan to reduce code with `toggle()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        $($(this).data('id')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` in that context references the checkbox.

`$('#dc')` is correct

EDIT

Based on your comment, you can get the value of the clicked checkbox like so:

```
var divId = $(this).attr('value')
```

And then you can use that value in the `div` selector:

```
$(divId).show() // or hide()
```

Comment: I know that $('#dc') would work, but I have many checkboxes and I want this function to work for all of them. I.e When checkbox value "#VR" is checked, div id="#VR" will show without writing a second identical function.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
               $($(this).data('id')).css('display','block');
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                $($(this).data('id')).css('display','none');   

            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="dieConstant" value="" data-id="#dc"> Show Dielectric Constant (dc)<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="dieConstant" value="" data-id="#dc1"> Show Dielectric Constant (dc1)<br>

<div id="dc" style="display:none">
    content dc
</div>

<div id="dc1" style="display:none">
    dc1
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    let div = $(this).attr("value");
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      $(div).show();
    } else {
      $(div).hide();

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="dieConstant" value="#dc"> Show Dielectric Constant<br>


<div id="dc" style="display:none">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry ! I will  be doing it. Thanks